# Threejs "Failed to generate a dem file using gdalwarp. gdalwarp is not installed."

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, gdalwarp, osx

I am trying to test out the new threejs plugin for QGis and have come across this error.

> Failed to generate a dem file using gdalwarp. gdalwarp is not
>   installed.

I have installed the latest version of QGis as well as GDAL framework and matplotlib for Mac from KyngChaos.

They have all been installed without error and am stuck as to where my trouble arises as it would appear that I have installed GDAL framework (assuming this includes GDALWARP).

Any pointers as to what I need to tweak so I can play with this seemingly great addition to QGIS plugins :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of Paths:

Look at [Qgis2threejs suggestions...](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Qgis2threejs-suggestions-td5095871.html#a5096206)  (for the first version of the plugin)

> As I use Mac OS X and the QGIS version of Kyngchaos, the path of gdalwarp is /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/gdalwarp but this QGIS version does not recognize  the PATHs defined in the UNIX environment of MAC OS X ie:

```
    export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
    which gdalwarp
   /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdalwarp
```

For the 0.6 version, replace the line 110 of **qgis2threejstools.py**

```
cmd = "gdalwarp " + u" ".join(options)
```

by:

```
cmd = "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/Programs/gdalwarp" + u" ".join(options)
```

and remove the conditional statements (lines 116...120)

```
#if not os.path.exists(demfilename):
#....
```

and line 89:

```
# options.append("--config GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8 NO")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response gene :-) I'll give that a go with fresh eyes and let you know how I go. I am positive about it as it sounds like you had the same issue.